# IsAuthenticated is always false in ASP.NET with keycloak after succesful login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, keycloak, openid

I have succesfuly integrated Keycloak into my ASP.NET MVC application like so

```
            const string persistentAuthType = "keycloak_auth";

            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(persistentAuthType);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = persistentAuthType,
            });

            // Configure Auth0 authentication
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "keycloak_auth",
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authorityserver,
                RedirectUri = "http://localhost:13636/home",
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:13636",
                ClientSecret = clientSecret,
                RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
               
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code,
                Scope = "openid profile email",

            });
```

The test is ok, the Keycloak login page is displayed and i can login to it and it redirects to my /home controller correctly, however in the Home controller, when checking the User.Identity.IsAuthenticated it always return to false;

```
 public class HomeController : BaseController
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)          // <-- always false
            {
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    RedirectUri = Url.Action("Index", "Home")
                }, "keycloak_auth");
                return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
            }
            ViewBag.Title = "Home";
            return View();
        }
```

Why is this? Am I missing something?
since it is false, it always loops around and calls /home does 'crashing'

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the AddAuthentication() part below, that is required for it to work.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddCookie(options =>
{
  ...
}).AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
  ...
}
```

Also, do you have these two as well?

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: i dont think i have those options, im using ASP.NET MVC and not .NET Core

Comment: look at https://nahidfa.com/posts/identityserver4-and-asp-.net-mvc/ and the SignInAsAuthenticationType?